# Return single row from matching on multiple condition on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’ve following data in the table

```
id  Parameter   Value
10  Location    New York
10  Business    SME
9   Location    London
9   Business    SME
8   Location    New York
8   Business    IT
```

I want a single row from the following:

```
where location = New York and Business = SME
```

The below Query returns multiple rows due to OR condition.

```
SELECT * from TABLEA WHERE
(Parameter='Location' AND DataValue = 'New York')
OR ( Parameter='Business' AND DataValue = 'SME')
```

Update:

Thanks everyone for your reply, exists and inner join resolved my problem. But in my case the column checking will happen dynamically based on certain conditions. 
i.e.

```
 id  Parameter   Value       Value2    Value3 
 10  Location    New York    L1
 10  Business    SME         B1 
  9   Location   London      L2
  9   Business   SME         B2
  8   Location   New York    L3
  8   Business   IT          B3
```

Could it be possible to develop some query to check the columns dynamically?

Comment: Key/value tables are really a pain to work with. Is this table given or can you change this to a real table with columns for location and business? If you can, do so. Apart from that, a column called ID should always be a unique identifyer for a record in a table. It isn't in your case, so change its name to something meaningful, such as id_company if it references a record in a company table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT * from TABLEA T WHERE
(Parameter='Location' AND DataValue = 'New York' )
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TABLEA T1 WHERE T1.id= T.id 
        AND ( T1.Parameter='Business' AND T1.DataValue = 'SME'))
```

Comment: Not quite right, OP wants all data to be in a single row, not just to return a single row.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers here may work, but the joins can add unnecessary cost to the query, or the query itself may be hard to generalise.

One approach that scans the data just once *(no joins)* and is reasonably general, is to take your query, aggregate the results and check that sufficient number of your criteria were matched.

Individual attributes/parameters can then be picked out of the results using conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'Location' THEN DataValue END)   AS Location,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'Business' THEN DataValue END)   AS Business
FROM
  TABLEA
WHERE
     (Parameter='Location' AND DataValue = 'New York')
  OR (Parameter='Business' AND DataValue = 'SME')
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

This query is reasonably usual when querying an "Entity, Attribute, Value" table.  In your case the "Entity" is the `id` column, the "Attribute" is the `parameter` column, and the "Value" is the `DataValue` column.

As you will no doubt find out, however, these are ***very poor*** for searching in the way you are doing.  This is because many different entities may match some but not all of your conditions, all of which have to be checked, making it very slow.

They're very fast when the query has `WHERE id = ???` and you then want to pick out the location or the business, it's just that they're very slow the way you are using them.

I recommend searching for use cases, optimisations and alternatives for "EAV" tables.

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice way to do it too. Unfortunately someone upvoted most of the wrong answers :/

Comment: I consider this the perfect answer.

Comment: @DavidG : That's life, hopefully more people will up-vote the aggregate based answers.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Flattery will get you every where!

Answer (score 2):

You need to JOIN the table back to itself to get two rows into a single one. For example:

```
SELECT 
    Businesses.ID,
    Locations.[Value] AS [Location],
    Businesses.[Value] AS Business
FROM TABLEA AS Locations
JOIN TABLEA AS Businesses
    ON Locations.ID = Businesses.ID
WHERE Locations.Parameter='Location' AND Locations.DataValue = 'New York'
AND Businesses.Parameter='Business' AND Businesses.DataValue = 'SME'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd typically aggregate over a key/value table when you want to get an entity that matches multiple attributes:

```
select id
from keyvalue
group by id
having count(case when parameter = 'Location' AND datavalue = 'New York' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when parameter = 'Business' AND datavalue = 'SME' then 1 end) > 0;
```

or

```
select id
from keyvalue
where (parameter = 'Location' AND datavalue = 'New York')
   or (parameter = 'Business' AND datavalue = 'SME')
group by id
having count(distinct parameter) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TOP(1)` expression.

```
SELECT TOP(1) ... columns ... FROM my_table WHERE ... filter condition ...
```

Comment: Note that OP wants a *single row* where location = New York and Business = SME. This query will return only one of those values.

Answer (score 0):

Change **OR** for **AND**:

```
SELECT * from TABLEA WHERE
(Parameter='Location' AND DataValue = 'New York' )
AND ( Parameter='Business' AND DataValue = 'SME')
```

Comment: This will now return zero rows and makes even less sense than the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use TOP keyword.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from TABLEA WHERE
(Parameter='Location' AND DataValue = 'New York' )
OR ( Parameter='Business' AND DataValue = 'SME')
```

Comment: This is just a hack around OPs problem. You're just arbitrarily choosing a random row to return.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But, I have pointed out the TOP keyword to him. Now he has to use his brain on which row he is willing to fetch.

Comment: Note that OP wants a *single row* where location = New York and Business = SME. This query will return only one of those values.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the following:

```
SELECT Top 1 * from TABLEA 
WHERE (Parameter='Location' AND DataValue = 'New York') 
AND ( Parameter='Business' AND DataValue = 'SME')
```

Comment: Note that OP wants a *single row* where location = New York and Business = SME. This query will return only one of those values.